# Can you set an element's padding based on the depth of its nesting using SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm designing a dropdown menu with many levels and need to set the padding of the `li` option based on the depth of the nesting.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <ul>
           <li> i </li>
           <li> ii </li>
           <li> iii </li>
        </ul>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

The option `2` has two suboptions: `a` and `b`. The option `b` has 3 suboptions: `i`,`ii`,`iii`

Is there any way I can have all `li` on the first level have 16px padding-left, and all `li`s after that have padding-left of something like `(parent li's padding-left) + 20px`?

Note: what I *really* want is all options one after the other and each option's padding is based on its level of nesting without having to write an explicit class for each level.

Edit: Here's a basic codepen [Codepen for the main problem](https://codepen.io/malaoun/pen/pobZJxa): What I want is the hover background for each item to extend to the full width of the main container

Comment: **Danger**: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`. Only `<li>` elements may be children of a `<ul>`. (If you fix that you'll probably find your problem much simplified)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! Didn't realize that.

Comment: Agreed the new uls need to be in an li element. I think you'll find if padding is applied to li elements that it will multiply on its own. If not, use pseudo elements to affect each sub layer individually.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Yes, the padding of the total row adds up (container padding + row padding), but if I change the background color of one single `<li>` element that's deeply nested, the entire row is not that color. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: To dynamically increase padding you can do something like this:

```
ul:nth-child(1) > * {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Check the snippet below:

```css
ul:nth-child(1) > * {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>a</li>
         <li>b</li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li> i </li>
               <li> ii </li>
               <li> iii </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're specifying the padding-left explicitly per level. My real goal is to have the padding of each li element to dynamically increase based on the nesting depth. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/malaoun/pen/pobZJxa). What I want here, is the hover background color to extend to the full width of the container.

Comment: Your question said you did not want to specify a class for each level?

Comment: Ideally yes. I want to be able to just add any number of <ul> sub menus (at whatever depth) and for the padding of that ul's children to increase by itself.